# Running JAR in Hadoop on Google Cloud using Yarn-client

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, google-compute-engine, hadoop-yarn

i want to run a JAR in Hadoop on Google Cloud using Yarn-client.

i use this command in the master node of hadoop

```
spark-submit --class find --master yarn-client find.jar
```

but it return this error

```
    15/06/17 10:11:06 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop-m-on8g/10.240.180.15:8032
15/06/17 10:11:07 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-m-on8g/10.240.180.15:8032. Already tried 0 
time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

What is the problem? In case it is useful this is my yarn-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
     <configuration>
      <!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
      <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
        <value>/yarn-logs/</value>
        <description>
          The remote path, on the default FS, to store logs.
        </description>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>hadoop-m-on8g</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>5999</value>
        <description>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it looks like the YARN ResourceManager may be unhealthy for unknown reasons; you can try to fix yarn with the following:

```
sudo sudo -u hadoop /home/hadoop/hadoop-install/sbin/stop-yarn.sh
sudo sudo -u hadoop /home/hadoop/hadoop-install/sbin/start-yarn.sh
```

However, it looks like you're using the Click-to-Deploy solution; Click-to-Deploy's Spark + Hadoop 2 deployment actually doesn't support Spark on YARN at the moment, due to some bugs and lack of memory configs. You'd normally run into something like this if you just try to run it with `--master yarn-client` out-of-the-box:

```
15/06/17 17:21:08 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application report from ASM: 
   appMasterRpcPort: -1
   appStartTime: 1434561664937
   yarnAppState: ACCEPTED

15/06/17 17:21:09 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application report from ASM: 
   appMasterRpcPort: -1
   appStartTime: 1434561664937
   yarnAppState: ACCEPTED

15/06/17 17:21:10 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application report from ASM: 
   appMasterRpcPort: 0
   appStartTime: 1434561664937
   yarnAppState: RUNNING

15/06/17 17:21:15 ERROR cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Yarn application already ended: FAILED
15/06/17 17:21:15 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/metrics/json,null}
15/06/17 17:21:15 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/kill,null}
```

The well-supported way to deploy is a cluster on Google Compute Engine with Hadoop 2 and Spark configured to be able to run on YARN is to use [bdutil](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bdutil). You'd run something like:

```
./bdutil -P <instance prefix> -p <project id> -b <bucket> -z <zone> -d  \
    -e extensions/spark/spark_on_yarn_env.sh generate_config my_custom_env.sh
./bdutil -e my_custom_env.sh deploy

# Shorthand for logging in to the master
./bdutil -e my_custom_env.sh shell

# Handy way to run a socks proxy to make it easy to access the web UIs
./bdutil -e my_custom_env.sh socksproxy

# When done, delete your cluster
./bdutil -e my_custom_env.sh delete
```

With `spark_on_yarn_env.sh` Spark should default to `yarn-client`, though you can always re-specify `--master yarn-client` if you want. You can see a more detailed explanation of the flags available in `bdutil` with `./bdutil --help`. Here are the help entries just for the flags I included above:

```
-b, --bucket
  Google Cloud Storage bucket used in deployment and by the cluster.

-d, --use_attached_pds
  If true, uses additional non-boot volumes, optionally creating them on
  deploy if they don't exist already and deleting them on cluster delete.

-e, --env_var_files
  Comma-separated list of bash files that are sourced to configure the cluster
  and installed software. Files are sourced in order with later files being
  sourced last. bdutil_env.sh is always sourced first. Flag arguments are
  set after all sourced files, but before the evaluate_late_variable_bindings
  method of bdutil_env.sh. see bdutil_env.sh for more information.

-P, --prefix
  Common prefix for cluster nodes.

-p, --project
  The Google Cloud Platform project to use to create the cluster.

-z, --zone
  Specify the Google Compute Engine zone to use.
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for the help , i try your command but if i try to launch the spark-submit , it report this INFO yarn.Client: Application report from ResourceManager: 
         application identifier: application_1434614478260_0003
         appId: 3
         clientToAMToken: null
         appDiagnostics: 
         appMasterHost: N/A
         appQueue: default
         appMasterRpcPort: -1
         appStartTime: 1434617006538
         yarnAppState: ACCEPTED
         distributedFinalState: UNDEFINED
         appTrackingUrl: http://hadoop-m-565h:8088/proxy/application_1434614478260_0003/
      appUser

Comment: if i try to use bdutil , at the secondo step when i deply the custom_env it return this Thu Jun 18 13:00:11 UTC 2015: Command failed: wait ${SUBPROC} on line 326.
Thu Jun 18 13:00:11 UTC 2015: Exit code of failed command: 1
Thu Jun 18 13:00:11 UTC 2015: Detailed debug info available in file: /tmp/bdutil-20150618-130008-iVA/debuginfo.tx
t

Comment: Do you have the contents of /tmp/bdutil-20150618-130008-iVA/debuginfo.txt? You can send them to gcp-hadoop-contact@google.com if you don't want to post it here.

Comment: it repeat 3 times each error : NAME ZONE MACHINE_TYPE INTERNAL_IP EXTERNAL_IP STATUS         ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Insufficient Permission                        ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Some requests did not succeed:                   Thu Jun 18 23:13:09 UTC 2015: Exited 1 : gcloud --project=provadatamining-979 --quiet --verbosity=info compute instances create hadoop-w-1 --machine-type=n1-standard-4 --image=debian-7-backports --network=default --scopes storage-full --boot-disk-type=pd-standard --zone=us-central1-f

Comment: Ah, are you running bdutil from inside a VM? If so, you need to make sure the VM has "service accounts" enabled with "compute" and "storage full" scopes. Under the hood, bdutil runs "gcloud compute instances create", and also uses "gsutil" for staging files.

Comment: i run the command in the shell of the master node, it is correct? i connect with the master using the SSH button on Compute Engine VM Instances . I have Read Only Compute permission and storage full. Can i change Read Only with Read Write? Where i use your command with bduilt? thansk a lot

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion. bdutil is typically supposed to be run on your own workstation or alternatively on a single GCE VM that you may have created using the GUI for GCE or maybe "gcloud compute instances add". If you have `gcloud` installed on your own workstation, you should go ahead and run bdutil from your workstation. bdutil is to be used instead of using Click-to-Deploy at all; instead of Click-to-Deploy creating your Hadoop cluster, bdutil will create your Hadoop cluster by provisioning new GCE VMs and then running setup scripts on them.

Comment: thanks i have confuse. I have create all the cluster using click-to-deploy. This dont create the configuration of the machine automatically? it is possible than there is an error on my scala code? if you want i post it, i want  search a word in a txt file in the bucket using yarn, if i use --master yarn-client it run but only on master machine, if i use --master yarn-cluster it dont run.

Comment: As I mentioned, Click-to-Deploy will create a cluster that is fine for --master spark://hadoop-m-asdf:7077 but it does not support Spark on YARN. If you want to use Spark on YARN you should deploy using bdutil instead.

Comment: Hi i have deploy using bdutil , the problem is that, how i can instal hadoop and spark on the machine? because there arent in the machine that i create using bdutil

Comment: another thing , if i try to create using bduilt on my workstation it return the same error sab 20 giu 2015, 17.38.26, CEST: Exited 1 : gcloud --project=provadatamining-979 --quiet --verbosity=info compute disks create --size=500 --type=pd-standard hadoop-w-0-pd --zone=us-central1-a

Comment: Normally if you deploy using bdutil then everything is already installed on the cluster and running already, including Hadoop and Spark. Sounds like the root of the problem here is that bdutil isn't working due to authorization issues. bdutil requires the same permissions as it takes to run "gcloud compute instances create foo-instance". If you're able to deploy a VM using "gcloud compute instances create" then you can run bdutil from that same machine. If not, then bdutil won't work.